# symfony2 and throwing exception error

Tags: php, exception, symfony

I am trying to throw exceptions and I am doing the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
```

I am then using them the following way:

```
 throw new HttpNotFoundException("Page not found");
   throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');
```

however I am getting errors like HttpNotFoundException is not found etc.

Is this the best way to throw exceptions?

Comment: It's normal to throw them as your first example, throw new Exception('Message'); So long as you've imported the exception class as you seem to have done with a use statement it ought to work. Possibly more to this that you are not showing - can you post your actual class headers and exception stack trace?

Comment: error I get is: Fatal error: Class 'Rest\UserBundle\Controller\HttpNotFoundException' not found in /Users/jinni/Sites/symfony.com/src/Rest/UserBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Comment: I have included use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception at top

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

and

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");
```

I think you got it a bit backwards :-)

Comment: It does not send 404 status

Answer (score 9):

If its in a controller, you can do it this way :

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find entity.');
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the controller**, you can simply do:

```
public function someAction()
{
    // ...

    // Tested, and the user does not have permissions
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException("You don't have access to this page!");

    // or tested and didn't found the product
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');

    // ...
}
```

In this situation, there'se no need to include the `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpNotFoundException;` at the top. The reason for that is that you're not using the class directly, like using the constructor.

**Outside the controller**, you must indicate where the class can be found, and throw an exception as you would normally do. Like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

// ...

// Something is missing
throw new HttpNotFoundException('The product does not exist');
```

or

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

// ...

// Permissions were denied
throw new AccessDeniedException("You don't have access to this page!");
```